# Weight Loss: Static Equilbrium

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, body-weight

My weights has reached the static equilibrium from more than 1 year between 77-79 KG. I wanted to make it 74 Kg, but no success so far.

Is it somehow related to testosterone? Would it be safe to take testosterone supplements or it has consequences?

Comment: More details please.

Comment: We can't really say over the internet what might be the reason for your *static equilibrium* in weight, but we might answer the question on adverse effects of testosterone supplements. However, the more research you do yourself and the more specific your question is, the more detailed and specific answer you are going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weight will not be 74kg from 77-79 KG maybe because you don't exert much effort to reach it? You don't have that kind of determination to achieve it. I know you will tell me that you do everything to lose weight but I think it's not enough because you're still struggling.

I understand, it's not easy to lose weight that much because it requires you to be serious and focus on your goals. You need to [change your lifestyle starting from the way you eat, sleep and exercise](https://behealthy.today/healthy-weight-loss-diet-and-exercise/).
Being healthy starts really in the kitchen, you should avoid alcoholic drinks, pizza, burgers and eating in fast food chain. Start eating healthy foods or make your own healthy recipes and have fun.
If you are planning to go to the gym I suggest you get a gym instructor, in that way he/she can monitor on your improvements. 
You need also to [drink more water every day](https://behealthy.today/water-weight-loss-effects/) before you start eating and every before and after your workout. Have a good sleep and everything will be fine.
I know you can do it. AJA!!

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Stackexchange network operates somewhat differently than a forum, it is intended to be a knowledge base. This is why [reliable references are required](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), especially on Health. You can always [edit] your answer to add some. For more information on how the site works, please take our [tour] or visit the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate your TDEE, adjust your calories required per day to keep losing weight, a deficit of 300-500 or so, depending on your preference.

Losing weight is all about making sure you take in (eat) less calories than you use.

Comment: I know that this might seem like common sense/general knowledge, but if we insist on references we have to do so for all answers, especially for the part where you have a quantitative recommendation - it should be fairly easy to add references for this one.

Answer (score -2):

Testosterone might have some indirect influence in this, but the bottom line is that your change in weight is decided by your caloric intake versus how many calories you burn.

That's really all you should focus on. If you want to lose extra weight, you either need to increase your physical activity (how many calories you burn) or reduce how much you eat (how many calories you intake) or both.

A little routine cardio exercise (running) will help you achieve this easily.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do work at Gym 2 Hours, 6 Days a week, but I am stuck at that weight. Can some medicines Help me to loose that 4-5 Kg extra weight.

Comment: I know that this might seem like common sense/general knowledge, but if we insist on references we have to do so for all answers.